# How can i convert an AC output from an outlet to a digital signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal, frequency, frequency-measurement

I´m making a digital frequency meter and want to compare the frequency from an outlet with a stable 1hz frequency from a crystal using an AND logic gate. However, I´m not sure how can i get a digital signal from the outlet. I will be using this project to measure frequencies from a function generator as well.
I deeply appreciate any help.

Edit: By "outlet" i mean a wall outlet with 127-220v 60hz, and the range is from 0 up to 99kHz. I´m a novice to digital electronics, so i thought an op amp was the best idea 
Edit 2: i just want to know a way to get a digital signal out of an AC input so i can use with digital ICs.

Comment: Eh. Strap a resistor to an optoisolator and use that instead.

Comment: ... But use an optoisolator capable of standing off your mains voltages (which I assume is what you mean by "outlet") and/or add voltage dividers.

Comment: (1) What is an "outlet"? (2) If you mean a mains voltage then that will be at 50 or 60 Hz. What use is "comparing" it with a 1 Hz signal? (3) Why do you have to use an operational amplifier? (They are analog, not digital.)

Comment: If making a general purpose frequency counter, which is what it seems you are attempting except that you want to apply it to this circumstance as well, I probably would not approach this so specifically. But your question is unclear. I think you need to help us by specifying the range of frequencies you'd like to count, how often you want a measurement displayed, etc. Write some specifications, would you? Or, get rid of the "I will be using this project to measure ... from a function generator" part of your question, if that's not important to you.

Comment: I´m intending to make a general purpose frequency meter actually

Comment: @LucasF.  Take Olin's approach, but consider turning that concept into an "adapter" that you use with a general purpose frequency counter that you build. Once you figure out what you want as a "standard input" for your counter, you can develop any number of such adapters so that you can accommodate a variety of signal source situations, with safety and ease. So I'd recommend dividing this project into at least two halves, with adapters for TTL, CMOS, AC line comparator, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is best done with a opto-isolator.  That not only handles the level conversion, but also isolates the digital signal from the AC line.

All you really need is a single opto-isolator.  However, if you want to also get a good idea of when the zero crossings are, two opto-isolators will give you a nicely symmetric signal:

[image]

Each half of the AC waveform turns on one of the opto-isolators.  That drives the output either positively low or positively high.  The other half of the waveform activates the other opto, which drives the output actively to the other state.  Each LED protects the other from large reverse voltages.

R1 and R2 cause the digital signal to float in the middle when there is no AC voltage applied to the input.  When used with a Schmitt trigger input, that keeps the input from getting toggled from stray pickup.  By measuring the analog level of OUT, you can distinguish between no input, versus stuck at one polarity, like DC applied.

Again, you don't need all this fanciness, but it's something I've used for a universal AC detector that can also sense the presence and polarity of rectified AC.

R3-R8 limit the current thru the LEDs.  In this case, multiple 0805 resistors were used instead of single larger 120 kΩ resistor.  This was done for stocking reasons.  20 kΩ 0805 resistors were already used in many other places.  Having to buy small quantities of 120 kΩ resistors resistors that can handle the power and voltage would have cost more.

This circuit can be used to sense AC line voltage anywhere in the world.  The total value of the input resistance, the power dissipation, and the minimum current transfer ratio of the optos have been carefully taken into account.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, what do you think is wrong?